# How to get the distance that a body has moved during a box2D world step?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to implement linear interpolation and a fixed time step for my game loop. I'm using the libGDX engine and box2D. I'm attempting to find the amount the simulation moves my character's body during a world step like this:

```
  old_pos = guyBody.getPosition();
  world.step(STEP_TIME, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);
  new_pos = guyBody.getPosition();
  printLog(new_pos.x-old_pos.x);
```

This returns 0 each time. The simulation works fine, and the body definitely moves each step.

Additional code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    accumulator+=delta;
    while (accumulator>=STEP_TIME){
        accumulator-=STEP_TIME;
        stepWorld();
    }
    alpha = accumulator/STEP_TIME;
    update(delta);
    //RENDER 
}


    private void stepWorld() {
       old_pos = guyBody.getPosition();
       old_angle = guyBody.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
       world.step(STEP_TIME, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);
       new_angle = guyBody.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
       new_pos = guyBody.getPosition();
    }
```

I'm attempting to use alpha to check how far I am in between physics steps so I can interpolate a Sprite's position.

Thanks!

Comment: try `printLog(new_pos.x)` and `printLog(old_pos.x)`, what are the values?

Comment: They update, but they're always the same:
I/OUT:: -54.899673
I/OUT:: -54.899673
I/OUT:: --

I/OUT:: -54.229126
I/OUT:: -54.229126
I/OUT:: --

I/OUT:: -53.55858
I/OUT:: -53.55858
I/OUT:: --

Comment: Notice how new_pos and old_pos is the same??

Comment: Yes, shouldn't they be different?

Comment: Yes, it should based on your requirement, but clearly there's a loop involved, just store the "old_pos" outside the loop. You have provided limited code, so it is hard to see what is going on.

Comment: Added some more code, let me know if anything else should be added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133051/discussion-between-almost-a-beginner-and-sullysunday).

Comment: I can't access chat for some reason. Thanks for your help but I guess I'm just going to set aside this issue for tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body's `getPosition` method is returning [Vector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html) reference - that means that you not copying it by value but only assign "pointer" on position object to `old_pos`/`new_pos`. However you are assigning it once before `step` and then after `step` all in all both variables keeps **the same object** with state after `step` already.

What you need to do is to copy position vector by value - to do this you can use Vector's `cpy()` method.

Your code should looks like

```
old_pos = guyBody.getPosition().cpy();
world.step(STEP_TIME, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);
new_pos = guyBody.getPosition().cpy();
printLog(new_pos.x-old_pos.x);
```

If you do not use `y` coordinate you should also consider keeping only `x` in float type variable to not copy whole object (however it should not really impact your performance).

Comment: That makes so much sense, thanks. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted response does answer my question, I wanted to add some information I figured out while trying to get this to work that I wish I knew at the beginning of this.

If you're going to use a fixed timestep for your physics calculations (which you should), you should also interpolate(or extrapolate) a Sprite's position between physics steps. In my code, the screen is being rendered more often than the world is being stepped:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    accumulator+=delta;
    while (accumulator>=STEP_TIME){
        accumulator-=STEP_TIME;
        stepWorld();
    }
    alpha = accumulator/STEP_TIME;
    update(delta);
    //RENDER using alpha
}
```

To avoid a jittery rendering of moving objects, render Sprites or Textures at their positions, modified by alpha. Since alpha is the ratio of your accumulator to the step time, it will always be between 0 and 1.

You then need to find how much your body is moving during one step. This can be done with the accepted answer or using the body velocity:

```
newPos = oldPos + body.getLinearVelocity()*STEP_TIME*alpha
```

Then just render Sprite at the new position and you should see smooth movement with your fixed timestep at most frame rates.